# Trying to understand why Sqlite3 queries through Anaconda/python (JupyterLab) take ~1,000 times longer than if ran through DB Browser

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, anaconda

I have a Python script to import data from raw csv/xlsx files. For these I use Pandas to load the files, do some light transformation, and save to an sqlite3 database. This is fast (as fast as any method). After this, I run some queries against these to make some intermediate datasets. These I run through a function (see below).

More information: I am using Anaconda/Python3 (3.9) on Windows 10 Enterprise.

UPDATE:

> Just as information for anybody reading this, I ended up going back to
> just using standalone python (still using JupyterLab though)... I no
> longer have this issue. So not sure if it is a problem with something
> Anaconda does or just the versions of various libraries being used for
> that particular Anaconda distribution (latest available). My script
> runs more or less in the time that I would expect using Python 3.11
> and the versions pulled in by pip for Pandas and sqlite (1.5.3 and
> 3.38.4).

Python function for running sqlite3 queries:

```
def runSqliteScript(destConnString, queryString):
    '''Runs an sqlite script given a connection string and a query string
    '''
    try: 
        print('Trying to execute sql script: ')
        print(queryString)
        cursorTmp = destConnString.cursor()
        cursorTmp.executescript(queryString)
    except Exception as e: 
        print('Error caught: {}'.format(e))
```

Because somebody asked, here is the function that creates the "destConnString", though it's called something else in the actual function call, but is the same type.

```
def createSqliteDb(db_file): 
    ''' Creates an sqlite database at direct/file name specified
    '''
    conSqlite = None
    try:
        conSqlite = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conSqlite
    except Error as e: 
        print('Error {} when trying to create {}'.format(e, db_file))
```

Example of one of the queries (I commented out journal mode/synchronous pragmas after it didn't seem to help at all):

```
-- PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
-- PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL;

BEGIN; 

drop table if exists tbl_1110_cop_omd_fmd; 
COMMIT; 
BEGIN; 
create table tbl_1110_cop_omd_fmd as

select 
        siteId, 
        orderNumber, 
        familyGroup01, familyGroup02, 
        count(*) as countOfLines
from tbl_0000_ob_trx_for_frazelle
where 1 = 1
  -- and dateCreated between datetime('now', '-365 days') and datetime('now', 'localtime') -- temporarily commented due to no date in file
group by siteId, 
         orderNumber, 
         familyGroup01, familyGroup02
order by dateCreated asc
;
COMMIT
;
```

Here is a list of things that I have tried. Unfortunately, no matter what combination of things I have tried, it has ended up having one bottleneck or another. It seems there is some kind of write bottleneck from python to sqlite3, yet the pandas to_sql method doesn't seem to be affected by it. Complete list of all combinations of things that I have tried.

1. I tried wrapping all my queries in begin/commit statements. I put these in-line with the query, though I'd be interested in knowing if  this is the correct way to do this. This seemed to have no effect.
2. I tried setting the journal mode to WAL and synchronous to normal, again to no effect.
3. I tried running the queries in an in-memory database.

   - Firstly, I tried creating everything from scratch in the in-memory database. The tables didn't create any faster. Saving this in-memory database seems to be a bottleneck (backup method).
   - Next, I tried creating views instead of tables (again, creating everything from scratch in the in-memory database). This created really quickly. Weirdly, querying these views was very fast. Saving this in-memory database seems to be a bottleneck (backup method).
4. I tried just writing views to the database file (not in-memory). Unfortunately, the views take as long as the make tables when running from Python/sqlite.

I don't really want to do anything strictly in-memory for the database creation, as this python script is used for different sets of data, some which could have too many rows for an in-memory setup. The only thing I have left to try is to take the in-memory from scratch setup, make views instead of tables, read ALL the in-memory db tables with pandas (from_sql), then write ALL the tables to a file db with pandas (to_sql)... Hoping there is something easy to try to resolve this problem.

```
connOBData = sqlite3.connect('file:cachedb?mode=memory?cache=shared')
```

These take approximately 1,000 times or more longer than if I run these queries directly in DB Browser (an sqlite frontend).  These queries aren't that complex and run fine (in ~2-4 seconds) in DB Browser. All told, if I run all the queries in a row in DB Browser they'd run in 1-2 minutes. If I let them run through the Python script, it literally takes close to 20 hours. I'd expect the queries to finish in approximately the same time that they run in DB Browser.

Comment: What type of object is `destConnString`?  If it's a string, as the name suggests, then it surely wouldn't have a `.cursor()` method.

Comment: @JohnGordon, currently, it is the type that would be returned by ```connOBData = sqlite3.connect('file:cachedb?mode=memory?cache=shared')```

Normally, it is returned from a function from a call like this ```connOBData = createSqliteDb(tmpPath)```. The function is included below: 

```def createSqliteDb(db_file): 
    ''' Creates an sqlite database at direct/file name specified
    '''
    conSqlite = None
    try:
        conSqlite = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conSqlite
    except Error as e: 
        print('Error {} when trying to create {}'.format(e, db_file)) ```

Comment: I added the function in the question, since it was displaying without line returns in the comment.

Comment: Okay, so it's just a `Connection` object.

Comment: Just as information for anybody reading this, I ended up going back to just using standalone python (still using JupyterLab though)... I no longer have this issue. So not sure if it is a problem with something Anaconda does or just the versions of various libraries being used for that particular Anaconda distribution (latest available). My script runs more or less in the time that I would expect using Python 3.11 and the versions pulled in by pip for Pandas and sqlite (1.5.3 and 3.38.4).